# Why can't I add localization to my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to add a localization. I've read all those localization/internationalization guides from Apple and raywenderlich.com. I've marked all my code with NSLocalizedString macro, I've used genstrings to create Localizable.strings. But somehow I'm missing some important step.

When I try to add localization to my Localizable.strings I'm somehow restricted to English only.

When I try to add localization to project via "Editor"->"Add Localization" all language options are disabled.

Does anybody have any thoughts as to why am I restricted to English only? What have I missed?

I've tried to add localization to other projects with the same result. :(

Comment: Have you remembered to change your device's language preferences to test?

Comment: @CrimsonDiego I think the problem is in Xcode. He didn't get to deploying yet.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to first add your localizations to your project. Click on the project file, ensure that the project, not the target, is selected in the middle pane and then choose the "Info" screen. There's a area called "Localizations" where you can add languages. You should then be able to localize your resources.

[image: Important pieces]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly I was missing!

Comment: after press plus button I see empty list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283141/xcode-6-localization

Comment: i don't have any entry in this list and can't add one.

Comment: @surfrider you might try asking a new question with all the details.

Comment: I don't see any "Localizations" entry under Info, only Custom iOS Target Properties, Document Types, Exported UTIs, Imported UTIs, and URL Types...

Comment: @Cindeselia You have the app target selected, not the project. Check the highlighted item in the middle column of my screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible issue is that you are not selecting appropriately the project, which leads to all languages in the *Add localization* list being disabled.

By default the target may be selected, make sure you select the project instead. Then you can use the *Add localization* normally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just had a facepalm moment. Thanks Bruno!

Comment: I am new to iOS development and that saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Something which kept me busy for too long. I looked over the language I needed (Swedish) in the first list and took the one from the "Other" list. Well my phone or emulator didn't change at all to Swedish. But when I took Swedish from the first list it got nicely updated when changing the language settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

With Xcode 6, you can do it via Project Settings.

Comment: what  do you think about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283141/xcode-6-localization

Comment: How, please give the detail