# Importing xliff file into Xcode 9.4.1 creates (null) language files

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode9, xliff

Can't seem to find a fix for this.

Translators have completed the xliff file with Simplified Chinese. In Xcode I go to Editor --> Import Localizations and select the file which is zh-Hans.xliff. Xcode imports but then names it "(null)" in all areas of the project where it should be "(Chinese-Simplified)" (see screenshot)

[image]

When I change my iPhone language setting to Chinese-Simplified the app doesn't pick up any of the translations.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833821/why-cant-i-add-localization-to-my-ios-app

Comment: @ShauketSheikh thanks but none of those relate to my problem. I'm using the import feature, not adding localizations manually (although it may get to that if I can't get this to work)

Comment: @Tim, Would it be possible for you to share your xliff file, or part of it that creates a "null" language when imported? If you're unable to share actual translations, you can edit the xliff file you've received and remove `<body>` tags - the problem probably lies in the `<file>` / `<header>` tags